# how to access the dataframe with floating point index and column names

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have the dataframe like below

**df**:

```
                    138.750000 138.750111 138.750222
35.666556           695.6      700.3      709.5
35.666444           701.5      706.0      713.4
35.666333           717.8      717.5      720.4
```

How can I access the dataframe value

```
df[35.666556,138.750000]
```

> > 695.6

Doing this will give an error of float datatype error.

Thanks 
-Megha

Comment: Please read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples) on how to post a good pandas question.

Comment: df['138.750000'][35.666556] <------- should be.

Comment: the above assume columns names to be an object. If float names then it should be df[138.750000][35.666556]

Answer (score 0):

**df:**

```
                    138.750000 138.750111 138.750222
35.666556           695.6      700.3      709.5
35.666444           701.5      706.0      713.4
35.666333           717.8      717.5      720.4
```

---

```
df[138.750000][35.666556]
```

> 695.6